# Dotnet command adds reference path instead of reference name

Tags: .net, reference, add-references-dialog

I'm using the "dotnet add reference" command to add a reference to my Visual Studio project, but it's adding the path of the reference instead of the reference name. How can I make it add the reference name?
Following is the command which I have used [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference)

```
dotnet add vbproj/path/of/project reference vbproj/path/of/reference
```

[add reference from reference window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajXPN.png)

[add reference using dotnet command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seiRk.png)

Comment: what was the outcome in terms of the project file? did it add a `<ProjectReference>` or did it add a `<Reference>` ? the project file is what matters - what the IDE shows is ... meh, whatever; also: note that `<ProjectReference>` *is* specified by path; it is only `<PackageReference>` that is added purely as a name (using the external package source as a resolver)